# Bit-Shift a string to decode save file C++

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I am kinda trying to decode my save files. And I came up with this. But shifting the characters back from the save file doesn't seem to work properly. Only the numbers seem to recover correctly but all the other characters seem to change into strange symbols. As you can see I bit-shift the savecontent << 1 to the left, and on load I bit-shift the incoming line >> 1 to the right. But it doesn't work as I expected. Does bit-shift not work properly on strings?

```
void erGuiManager::SaveToFile(string filename) {
    ofstream ifs;
    ifs.open(filename, ios::binary);

    if (ifs.is_open())
    {
        string savecontent = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < guiItems.size(); i++) {
            if (dynamic_cast<erGuiBasicNode*>(guiItems[i])) {
                savecontent.append( dynamic_cast<erGuiBasicNode*>(guiItems[i])->save(true));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < savecontent.length(); i++) {
            savecontent[i] = savecontent[i] << 1;
        }
        ifs.write(savecontent.c_str(), strlen(savecontent.c_str()));
        ifs.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error: Unable to open file " << filename;
    }
}

void erGuiManager::LoadFromFile(string filename) {
    string line;
    string out;
    ifstream myfile(filename);
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                line[i] = line[i] >> 1;
            }
            out.append(PasteNodeFromString(line,true));
        }
        ConnectBezierLines(out);
        myfile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bit shifting is not reversible. You lose the highest bit in your case. This should still work if you only use basic ascii characters, that are all <128. A reversible operation would be rotate shift.

Comment: `ifs.write(savecontent.c_str(), strlen(savecontent.c_str()));` -- This will not work as expected if `savecontent` contains embedded `'\0'` characters.  The `strlen` will stop at the first null byte encountered.

Comment: Ok thanks Karsten I will see what that does!
@Aurel I just want a simple way to encode my files so not everyone can edit stuff from notepad. But it doesn't need to be unhackable or anything. I never did that before but first thing that came to mind was bit-shifting. But maybe it's not the best idea

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks I didn't realize that, I will take a look at it. It all worked fine before trying encoding, because I probably never used any /0 chars. But it might be a problem in the future, so thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I think it is a problem now.  You're not checking if the call to `string::append()`  is attaching null bytes, so the function could be easily broken.

Comment: I see I can just use savecontent.length() instead of strlen(savecontent.c_str())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator `>>` does an [arithmetic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift), this means all values >=64 will have a 1 in the highest bit, which is not what you want. In ASCII numbers are represented with values between 48 and 57, letters start at 65, so this is the reason why letters don't work.

A simple solution would be to explicitly set the highest bit to zero:

```
line[i] = (line[i] >> 1) & 0x7f;
```

This still means you can only use the lower half of the character set, i.e. values <127. A better solution would be to rotate shift:

```
line[i] = (line[i] << 1) | (line[i] >> 7)&0x01;
```

for encoding and

```
line[i] = (line[i] >> 1)&0x7f |(line[i]<<7);
```

Comment: _values >=64_ did you mean >=128?

Comment: value >= 128 means the highest bit is set, >=64 means the second highest is set. After shifting once to the left, values formerly >=64 have the highest bit set.

Comment: Thanks Karsten, I will try this!

Comment: While masking with `0x7f` seems to fix the issue, the root of the problem is that `line[i]` gets promoted to `int` first with sign extension. The fix for the root of problem is `static_cast<unsigned char>(line[i])` to disable the sign extension and no masking is necessary.

Comment: The masking worked good thanks Karsten! I had to use it in my case because I make use of chars above 127. Otherwise the solution of Maxim is also great!

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle issue with integral promotions (because there is no `operator<<` for `char`, so that it gets promoted to `int`) and sign extension.

Consider:

```
int main() {
    char a = 127;
    printf("%hhd\n", a);

    char b = a << 1;
    printf("%hhd\n", b);

    char c = b >> 1;
    printf("%hhd\n", c);
}
```

And its output:

```
127
-2
-1
```

As you can see the original value cannot be recovered.

The fix is to operate in `unsigned` space so that no sign extension happens:

```
int main() {
    char a = 127;
    printf("%hhd\n", a);

    char b = static_cast<unsigned char>(a) << 1;
    printf("%hhd\n", b);

    char c = static_cast<unsigned char>(b) >> 1;
    printf("%hhd\n", c);
}
```

Outputs correctly:

```
127
-2
127
```

In this particular case only `static_cast<unsigned char>(b) >> 1` is necessary to fix the issue, however, one should be cognizant about the integral promotions and sign extension when performing bit shifts.

Without cast:

```
char(254) >> 1 === int(-2) >> 1 === int(-1) === char(-1)
```

With cast:

```
unsigned char(254) >> 1 === int(254) >> 1 === int(127) === char(127)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Is it possible this option does not allow all characters? Because numbers and letters work fine but I use some symbols that are not working correctly for example this character: §

Comment: @AlexanderS. It throws away the highest order bit of `char`, so only values   in range [0, 127] can be recovered.

Comment: Yes I see, I use these characters above 127 to divide different properties in my save file (for example position and name of the node etc). Maybe I can exclude them from shifting or something. Thanks!

Comment: I went with the solution with masking because it seems to fix the problem also with characters above 127. But thanks for the answer I think it is a valuable answer anyway! Excluding them from shifting didn't work because after shifting I couldn't find the difference between shifted and unshifted chars anymore of-course.